# Issue with py- to-exe or cx_file or whatever. The code has several local submodules KIvymd+python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, kivymd

**Good eve folks,**
From the beggining I started with trying to use the pyinstaller based, auto-py-to-exe. I tryied every set of commands possible but It didn't work. The process of converting finishes but It returns tracebacks saying "Could not find a window provider" (error log in the picture below)
[image: picture].

Basically the settings I made were: add every file which was in the main.py directory in the 'additional files' menu; I filled the 'advance settings->hidden modules' with the names of all the file employed on the project.

In the most I used kivy and kivymd modules. I dont think It's necessary to post the scripts here once It runs without errors.

**I d appreciate a lot ya guys help!!** I already surfed all around the web, besides having watched every youtube tutorials but auto-py-to-exe/pyinstaller keeps not working. At last I also d like to share a cx_freeze unsucesful approach, I headed to **this alternative making a cx_freeze setup file to run with python 3.7:**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
Builder.load_file('Mainwidget.kv')
Builder.load_file('Popups.kv')
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from main_widget import Main_widget, ScanPopup, ModbusPopUp
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
from kivy.core.window import Window
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import random
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy_garden.graph import LinePlot
from TimesSeriesGraph import TimeSeriesGraph
from bdhandle import BDHandle


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
        Executable("main.py", base=base)
]

buildOptions = dict(
        packages = [],
        includes = ["kivy","kivymd","bdhandle","threading","main_widget","time","datetime","random","TimesSeriesGraph"],
        include_files = [],
        excludes = []
)

setup(
    name = "Refinery",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Refinery supervisory",
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
 )
```

At the end of the day I dont know which way is the best whether using cx_freeze or pyinstaller. So far neither of them worked, and as an begginer app curious, I had never generated exes before.
Waiting for your answers with help and patience! Cya

Edit (PYINSTALLER CONFIG DRAWN FROM AUTO-PY-TO-RUN):

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/bdhandle.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/main_widget.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/Mainwidget.kv;." --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/Popups.kv;." --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/Refinaria.png;." --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/requirements.txt;." --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/TimesSeriesGraph.py;." --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/Lib;Lib/" --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/Scripts;Scripts/" --add-data "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/venv;venv/" --hidden-import "kivy" --hidden-import "kivymd" --hidden-import "main_widget" --hidden-import "pyModbusTCP" --hidden-import "threading" --hidden-import "time" --hidden-import "datetime" --hidden-import "random" --hidden-import "TimesSeriesGraph" --hidden-import "bdhandle"  "C:/Users/User/source/repos/RefineryKVMD/main.py"

Comment: pyinstaller is the better option in my opinion.  create [mre] and I or someone else can show you hopefully

Comment: I edited the question  with the pyinstaller command! TY

Comment: Please post your code or create a [mre] that reproduces the same issue if you want assistance

Comment: It s true. The Project is this repo: https://github.com/caioalrodrig/supervis_kv_mbus

Comment: I managed to get your project to work.  Let me know if you are still looking for a solution to this and I can write a stepbystep